# Inserir imagem em 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Criei uma function para cadastrar imagens como se fosse um album;

Uma tabela para `capa` e uma tabela para `galeria`.

O HTML:

```
//Imagem da Capa
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="capa">Capa:</label>  
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="file" name="capa" class="form-control" required/>
     </div>
</div>

    // Imagens diversas                  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="imagem">Album </label>  
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="file[]" name="imagem" class="form-control" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
```

A function:

```
function criarAlbum($tabela1, $tabela2, $dados) {
$con = conectar();

$caminho = 'uploads/';

$nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
$nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"];
$tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"];

$nomeCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
$nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
$tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

$arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeCapa);
$extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
$arquivoCapa = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensaoCapa;


$arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
$extensao = end($arquivoArray);
$arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;

if (!is_dir($caminho)) {
    mkdir($caminho);
    chmod($caminho, 777);
}

// COMO VERIFICAR SE 2 ARQUIVOS FORAM MOVIDOS DE DIFERENTES INPUTS ?

if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {

   // Prepara a inserção no banco de dados
    $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela1(imagem) VALUES('$arquivo')");
    $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção

    $last = $inserir->lastInserId();

    $inserirCapa = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela2(idGaleria, imagem) VALUES($last, '$arquivoCapa')");
    $inseriCapa = $inserirCapa->execute(); // Execute a inserção

}
  if ($inseriCapa && $inseri) { // Caso a inserção ocorra bem exibira uma mensagem de sucesso.
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
  }
  else { // Caso a inserção ocorra mal exibira uma mensagem de erro.
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro ao inserir no banco de dados!</div>';
  }
}
```

O erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInserId() in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 293

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta a partir do seu comentário.

Comment: Acontece que fizeste o preparo da consulta, mas não vinculaste os parâmetros para a prepared statment, e a tua sintaxe está mal escrita.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui com nenhuma das opções mas me mostraram um "norte" muito bom.

Fiz deste jeito só que agora o problema é que só inseri uma imagem em album mesmo que eu selecione duas.

(A imagem da capa é inserida normalmente e o `lastid` tambem funciona)

O HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="nome">Nome</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Text input --> 
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="imagem">Capa:</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <input type="file" name="capa" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <!-- Text input-->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="imagem">Album:</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="form-control" multiple required/>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Button -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="salvar"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                          <button id="salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

A function:

```
function criar_album($tabela, $dados){
$con = conectar();
$caminho = 'uploads/';
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$qtd = count($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);
if ($qtd > 1){
    $nomeArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
    $nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
    $tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

    $arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeArquivoCapa);
    $extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
    $arquivoCapa = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensaoCapa;

    for ($i=0; $i < $qtd; $i++) { 
        $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"][$i];
        $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"][$i];

        if (!empty($nomeArquivo) && !empty($nomeArquivoCapa)) {

            $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
            $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
            $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;


            if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporarioCapa, $arquivoCapa)) {
                $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO capa(nome, imagem) VALUES('$nome', '$arquivoCapa')");
                        $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção

                        $last = $con->lastInsertId();
                        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
                            $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('$last', '$arquivo')");
                            echo var_dump($inserir);
                $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção    
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Erro!";
        }
    }
}
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
   }
}
```

Apos usar o `var_dump($inserir)` a query é exibida normalmente porem só uma...

> object(PDOStatement)[3]
>     public 'queryString' => string 'INSERT INTO album(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('8', 'uploads/fd4123f913ba671bc75f6493a3fd1f23.png')' (length=93)
>   Erro!

Comment: `if ($qtd > 1){`, não seria `if ($qtd > 0){` ?

Comment: Consegui resolver @rray, o problema era no loop do for para inserção e não neste `if` que voce mencionou.

Answer (score 0):

Quem tem o método [lastInserId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) é classe [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) e não a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), nesse caso troque `$inserir` por `$con`.

Troque:

```
$last = $inserir->lastInserId();
```

Por:

```
$last = $con->lastInserId();
```

Me parece melhor extrair a lógica do upload para uma função, isso vai eleminar a duplicação entre imagem e capa, sugiro que crie essa função, `mkdir()` e `chmod()` podem fazer parte dessa função se achar conveniente.

```
function upload($arquivo, $destino){
    $arq = pathinfo($arquivo['name']);
    $arq = $destino.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$arq['extension'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arq)){
        return array('nome' => $arq, 'nome_original' => $arquivo, 'sucesso' => true);
    }else{
        return array('nome' => '', 'nome_original' => $arquivo, 'sucesso' => false);
    }
}
```

Código principal:

```
$totalImagens = count($_FILE['imagem']['name']);
foreach($_FILE['imagem']['name'] as $imagem){
    $album[] = upload($_FILE['imagem'], $caminho);  
}

$capa = upload($_FILE['capa'], $caminho);
$imagensUpadas = array_count_values(array_column($album, 'sucesso'));

if($imagens_upadas['true'] == $totalImagens && capa['sucesso']){

    foreach($album as $imagem){
        $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela1(imagem) VALUES(?)");
        $inserir->execute(array($imagem['nome']));

        $last = $con->lastInserId();

        $inserirCapa = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela2(idGaleria, imagem) VALUES(?, ?)");
        $inseriCapa = $inserirCapa->execute(array($last, $capa['nome']));
    }   
}else{
  //Aqui pode fazer um função para apagar algum upload
}
```

Com ajuda de: [count of duplicate elements in an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13413465/1342547)

Comment: O Script não esta inserindo a imagem na tabela `galerias`a apenas em `capa`, como eu poderia verificar em `move_uploaded_file` mais de 1 arquivo movido ?

Comment: Essa resposta esta um pouco confusa, quando o `move_uploades_file`é chamado...não entendo muito bem ele ira executar os 2 ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, `upload()` faz o upload individual, `$capa` e `$imagem` tem as informações se o upload deu certo ou não e nome da imagem.

Comment: minha função de `criarAlbum` teria somente esse trecho de código que voce marcou como como principal ?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, isso mesmo

Comment: Os erros apresentados; `pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 260`, 
 `move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 263`

Comment: O nome(aleatorio) do arquivo fica em `$arq['nome']`, editei a resposta, @RafaelAcioly se precisar de algo mais fala ai.

Comment: Ahhh entendi no campo imagem vc envia mais de uma certo?

Comment: Sim, é um album! rs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29052/discussion-between-rafael-acioly-and-rray).

Comment: A grosso modo vc vai precisar de um `foreach` para `$_FILES['imagem']` @RafaelAcioly. vou editar novamente.

Answer (score 0):

`lastInserId()` deve estar relacionado com a conexão e não com o resultado da query.

Tenta substituir:

```
$last = $inserir->lastInserId();
```

Por:

```
$last = $con->lastInserId();
```

Além disso, fiz outro move_uploaded_file para salvar o arquivo na outra tabela, conforme seu comentário.

```
<?php

function criarAlbum($tabela1, $tabela2, $dados) {
    $con = conectar();

    $caminho = 'uploads/';

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"];

    $nomeCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
    $nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
    $tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

    $arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeCapa);
    $extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
    $arquivoCapa = $caminho . md5(time() . rand(3212, 15452)) . '.' . $extensaoCapa;


    $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
    $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
    $arquivo = $caminho . md5(time() . rand(3212, 15452)) . '.' . $extensao;

    if (!is_dir($caminho)) {
        mkdir($caminho);
        chmod($caminho, 777);
    }

// COMO VERIFICAR SE 2 ARQUIVOS FORAM MOVIDOS DE DIFERENTES INPUTS ?

    if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
        // Prepara a inserção no banco de dados
        $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela1(imagem) VALUES('$arquivo')");
        $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção

        $last = $con->lastInserId();
        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporarioCapa, $arquivoCapa)) {
            // Prepara a inserção no banco de dados
            $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela2(idGaleria, imagem) VALUES($last,'$arquivoCapa')");
            $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
        }
    }


    if ($inseriCapa && $inserir) { // Caso a inserção ocorra bem exibira uma mensagem de sucesso.
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
    } else { // Caso a inserção ocorra mal exibira uma mensagem de erro.
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro ao inserir no banco de dados!</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: O Script não esta inserindo a imagem na tabela `galerias` apenas em `capa`, como eu poderia verificar em `move_uploaded_file` mais de 1 arquivo movido ?

Comment: Editei minha resposta para atender a sua modificação. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: estes são os erros;
`explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 277`,  `end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 27`, `move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 288`, `Undefined variable: inseriCapa in /var/www/guilledev/includes/conexao.php on line 302`

Comment: Você está postando mais de um arquivo como capa?

Comment: não allan, apenas 1